# Задача "Подсчет букв в предложении"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Необходимо посчитать, сколько каких букв встречается в предложении
>   (одна и та же заглавная и прописная буква - это две разные буквы).

сделала так:

```
sentence = 'Jim quickly realized that the beautiful gowns are expensive'

count_letters = {}
sentence = sentence.split()
sentence = list(str(''.join((str(word)for word in sentence))))

myset = list(set(sentence))

mycount = []
i = 0
for letter in myset:
    for letter2 in sentence:
        if letter2 == letter:
            i += 1
    mycount.append(i)
    i = 0
count_letters = dict(zip(myset, mycount))
print(count_letters)
```

Можно ли сделать компактнее?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [11]: from collections import Counter

In [12]: c = Counter(sentence)

In [13]: c
Out[13]:
Counter({'J': 1,
         'i': 5,
         'm': 1,
         ' ': 8,
         'q': 1,
         'u': 3,
         'c': 1,
         'k': 1,
         'l': 3,
         'y': 1,
         'r': 2,
         'e': 8,
         'a': 4,
         'z': 1,
         'd': 1,
         't': 4,
         'h': 2,
         'b': 1,
         'f': 1,
         'g': 1,
         'o': 1,
         'w': 1,
         'n': 2,
         's': 2,
         'x': 1,
         'p': 1,
         'v': 1})
```

чтобы посмотреть 5 наиболее часто встречающихся букв:

```
In [15]: c.most_common(5)
Out[15]: [(' ', 8), ('e', 8), ('i', 5), ('a', 4), ('t', 4)]
```

---

[вот еще один вариант решения за один проход (сложность алгоритма `O(n)`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496555/5741205):

```
In [44]: d = {}

In [45]:  _ = [d.__setitem__(x,1+d.get(x,0)) for x in sentence if x != ' ']

In [46]: d
Out[46]:
{'J': 1,
 'i': 5,
 'm': 1,
 'q': 1,
 'u': 3,
 'c': 1,
 'k': 1,
 'l': 3,
 'y': 1,
 'r': 2,
 'e': 8,
 'a': 4,
 'z': 1,
 'd': 1,
 't': 4,
 'h': 2,
 'b': 1,
 'f': 1,
 'g': 1,
 'o': 1,
 'w': 1,
 'n': 2,
 's': 2,
 'x': 1,
 'p': 1,
 'v': 1}
```

NOTE: выглядит не очень читаемо ;-)

Comment: отлично! огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Данная задача очень часто встречается, и сильно пересекается с задачей, когда нужно составить список уникальных значений, пример алгоритма:

```
sentence = 'Jim quickly realized that the beautiful gowns are expensive'
result = {}
for letter in sentence:
    if letter not in result:
        result[letter] = 1
    else:
        result[letter] += 1
result.pop(" ")
print result
```

Также задачу можно решить в одну строку с помощью генератора словарей:

```
print {x: sentence.count(x) for x in sentence if x != " "}
# {'J': 1, 'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 8, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 5, 'h': 2, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 1, 'n': 2, 'q': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 2, 'r': 2, 'u': 3, 't': 4, 'w': 1, 'v': 1, 'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}
```

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!